# binary.Write to socket in go blocks

Tags: sockets, go

I'm trying to write a simple client-server application. It works fine with both sides on the same computer, but it blocks when run on two different computers. The computers are a RaspBerry Pi 2 and a MacBook Pro.

The problem is that the client blocks in binary.Write after a few good runs. Typically, the server that receives the data prints that it has received 63 and the client that sends the data prints that it will be sending 64.

If I ad the deadline to the server, it quits with a time-out. The client also has a deadline but doesn't time out.

I tried replacing the data by a simple byte array or just a single int. It still blocks. But the smaller the data is, the more times it goes right.

If I remove the Printf functions in the client, it also goes well for a longer time.

I also tried replacing the functionality of the server by a simple copy from the socket to STDIO (a tip I found here somewhere) but it still fails to come out of binary.Write.

Any idea?

Here is the complete source. There's some bogus stuff in there (the count loop, for example), but it's all really quite simple. Or am I mistaken?

```
package main

import (
    //  "bytes"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "runtime/trace"
    "time"
    "unsafe"
)

type TheMessageType struct {
    X             int32
    RestOfMessage [1000]byte
}

func listener(theCounter int, active bool, f *os.File) {
    var message TheMessageType
    var err error
    var conn net.Conn

    count := theCounter

    for {
        // Dial the server
        fmt.Printf("LISTENER %d: connecting to socket\n", count)
        conn, err = net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.1.113:49152")
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("LISTENER %d: not connected, retrying in 3 seconds\n", count)
            time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("LISTENER %d: connected\n", count)
            break
        }
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    // Loop writing to socket
    for {
        // Set deadline
        // conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second))

        // Print some info
        fmt.Printf("LISTENER %d: writing from %v to %v\n", count, conn.LocalAddr(), conn.RemoteAddr())

        // Prepare message to write to socket
        message.X = int32(count)
        theString := fmt.Sprintf("%d", count)
        copy(message.RestOfMessage[:], theString)

        // binary write directly to socket
        fmt.Printf("LISTENER %d: binary.Write this: %d, %s\n", count, message.X, message.RestOfMessage)

        f.Sync()
        err = binary.Write(conn, binary.LittleEndian, message)

        f.Sync()
        fmt.Printf("LISTENER %d: written\n", count)
        // time.Sleep(50 * time.Millisecond)
        checkError(err, "LISTENER")

        count = count + 1
    }
}

func main() {
    var myMessage TheMessageType
    var ln net.Listener
    var conn net.Conn
    var err error
    var theCount int
    var avgspeed, speed float64
    var speedlist [10]float64

    curspeed := 0

    const listenerActive = true
    const mainActive = false

    f, err := os.Create("theFile.out")
    trace.Start(f)

    t0 := time.Now()
    t1 := time.Now()

    transferSize := unsafe.Sizeof(myMessage)

    fmt.Printf("MAIN: timestamp %s ; size of transfers is %d\n", t0.String(), transferSize)

    if mainActive {
        fmt.Println("MAIN: listen")
        ln, err = net.Listen("tcp", ":49152")
        fmt.Println("MAIN: defer")
        defer ln.Close()
        fmt.Println("MAIN: checkError")
        checkError(err, "MAIN")
    }

    // launch listener
    if listenerActive {
        go listener(theCount, listenerActive, f)
    }

    for theCount = 1; ; theCount++ {

        if mainActive {
            fmt.Println("MAIN: accept")
            conn, err = ln.Accept()
            checkError(err, "MAIN")

            exit := false

            for !exit {
                // Set deadline
                // conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(2 * time.Second))

                // Print some info
                fmt.Printf("MAIN: reading on %v from %v\n", conn.LocalAddr(), conn.RemoteAddr())

                // move time
                t0 = t1

                // read from socket
                fmt.Println("MAIN: reader")

                f.Sync()
                err = binary.Read(conn, binary.LittleEndian, &myMessage)

                f.Sync()
                if err == io.EOF {
                    fmt.Println("EOF!")
                    exit = true
                    conn.Close()
                } else {
                    checkError(err, "MAIN")
                }

                // clear screen
                c := exec.Command("clear")
                c.Stdout = os.Stdout
                c.Run()

                // print received data
                fmt.Printf("MAIN: socket message received: %d, %s\n", myMessage.X, myMessage.RestOfMessage)

                // calculate speed & average
                t1 = time.Now()
                tdif := t1.Sub(t0)
                speed = float64(transferSize) / tdif.Seconds() / 1000000.0 * 8.0
                speedlist[curspeed] = speed
                curspeed = curspeed + 1
                if curspeed == 10 {
                    curspeed = 0
                }
                totalspeed := 0.0
                for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
                    totalspeed += speedlist[i]
                }
                avgspeed = totalspeed / 10

                // print speed
                fmt.Printf("MAIN: avg mbit/s %9.2f ; actual mbit/s: %9.2f\n", avgspeed, speed)
                // time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            }
        }
    }
}

func checkError(err error, name string) {
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "%s: Fatal error: %s\n", name, err.Error())
        //      panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", err.Error()))
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}
```

Here's the stacktrace of the client when it's blocked writing:

```
goroutine 1 [running]:
runtime.throw(0x1927b8, 0x5)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:527 +0x90 fp=0xc82004bd78 sp=0xc82004bd60
runtime.sigpanic()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/sigpanic_unix.go:27 +0x2ba fp=0xc82004bdc8 sp=0xc82004bd78
main.main()
    /Users/ple/dev/go/src/Peter-test/main.go:108 +0x33c fp=0xc82004bf50 sp=0xc82004bdc8
runtime.main()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:111 +0x2b0 fp=0xc82004bfa0 sp=0xc82004bf50
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1 fp=0xc82004bfa8 sp=0xc82004bfa0

goroutine 17 [syscall, locked to thread]:
runtime.goexit()
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1696 +0x1

goroutine 5 [trace reader (blocked)]:
runtime.ReadTrace(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace.go:339 +0x207
runtime/trace.Start.func1(0x5a42e0, 0xc82002a020)
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/trace.go:28 +0x18
created by runtime/trace.Start
    /usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace/trace.go:34 +0x78

goroutine 6 [runnable]:
reflect.Value.Index(0x1234c0, 0xc8204ac004, 0x51, 0x75, 0x12ac00, 0xc8204ac078, 0x48)
    /usr/local/go/src/reflect/value.go:823
encoding/binary.(*encoder).value(0xc8200475a0, 0x1234c0, 0xc8204ac004, 0x51)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/binary/binary.go:509 +0x808
encoding/binary.(*encoder).value(0xc8200475a0, 0x162ba0, 0xc8204ac000, 0x59)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/binary/binary.go:518 +0xb4f
encoding/binary.Write(0x621138, 0xc8200a2000, 0x621160, 0x289ef0, 0x162ba0, 0xc8204ac000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /usr/local/go/src/encoding/binary/binary.go:316 +0x1792
main.listener(0x0, 0x1, 0xc82002a020)
    /Users/ple/dev/go/src/Peter-test/main.go:59 +0xac8
created by main.main
    /Users/ple/dev/go/src/Peter-test/main.go:105 +0x332
```

Comment: Get a stack trace when your program is blocked to see *exactly* what everything is doing.

Comment: I'd like to, but I can't seem to get a trace. I tried using runtime/trace, but I haven't gotten it to work yet. It just writes "go 1.5 trace" and nothing more. I tried the http pprof, but it becomes unaccessible when the binary.Write blocks. And obviously, my program can't call Stack() because it's blocked. Is there any way that I can force a trace output when it runs before it blocks? One other thing I noticed: when it's blocked in binary.Write, CPU goes to 100%.

Comment: Just send the process a `SIGQUIT` and it will print a stack trace and exit.

Comment: Just added the stack trace to the original question. Thanks for the tip, I just found that out myself in the meantime.

Comment: That looks strange. Since it's intermittent, have you run this with the race detector? Does it happen when client/server are run on either host, or does it only happen one way?

Comment: Jim, I've run it with the race detector without succes: it still blocks. I can swap client and server and it still blocks. If both are on the same computer, then there is no problem. In the meantime, I've added an ACK back from server to client and it works longer, but still stops after about 15 minutes with an i/o time-out. I was considering SCTP instead of TCP because I'm sending fixed packets, but SCTP is not very common. Maybe I should try UDP? BTW, if it helps, I can publish my complete source above so you can just compile&run.

Comment: A couple more ideas for debugging, get some more stack traces and see if it's always in the same spot, or better yet, see if you can pull a cpu profile (from http/pprof) when it's blocked to see what is being called. If it were the network, I don't think you'd see the 100% CPU, which probably means it's stuck in a tight loop somewhere, maybe a bug in `encoding/binary` or `reflect`. This really isn't the place for this type of debugging. If you want to post a complete reproducer, we can probably better help with this over on the mailing list.

Comment: Jim, the complete source is in the question now. What mailing list are you talking about? I'm happy to move this to another location, as long as I find a solution one day :)

Comment: well, that solves it. If `mainActive == false`, you have a busy loop in main. The busy loop eventually prevents the scheduler from doing anything else. If you wait without the busy loop, this will work fine. (This *should* be able to continue in go1.5, albeit inefficiently and using 100%cpu, so there might be a related runtime bug, but it won't effect you if you "do it right"TM ;) )

Comment: oh and for future reference: [project information here](http://golang.org/project/), and the [official mailing list](https://groups.google.com/group/golang-nuts)

Comment: never mind the bug comment, this is expected. The scheduler can proceed until the GC needs to stop the world, then everything gets locked up.

Answer (score 0):

Jim's answer was right. Main goes into a busy loop. I solved it by passing a channel to listener and waiting for it at the end of main. The client "writes" to it after the for loop, which is an infinite loop, so main never ends. The program's been passing data ever since. I'll let it run overnight to be certain.

I'm only getting about 12.5Mbit/s, which is a bit funny. Connection is 1Gbit Wifi AC to a 100mbit Ethernet switch to the Raspberry Pi. But that's another question.

Thanks!